# MaxEnt with given variance (but mean unknown)

Tags: maximum-entropy

The MaxEnt distribution of $x \in (-\infty,\infty)$ with given mean and variance is the Gaussian. What happens when the mean is unknown? What is the MaxEnt distribution of $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$ with given variance (but unknown mean)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct. The normal distribution is the MaxEnt distribution for given variance, irrespective of the value of the mean (this is because differential entropy is "translation-invariant", it does not depend on location).

Note that the issue here is not whether a moment is "known" or "unknown", but rather whether we need to compare distributions that have the same value for that moment.

So, among distributions with the same variance and possibly different means, the normal is the MaxEnt distribution.

**PS:** The [wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Other_examples) for MaxEnt distributions is therefore **wrong** in showing the Normal to be Max Ent for given variance *and* mean.

Comment: So a consequence of this is that "the" maxent distribution with given variance, but unknown mean is not unique! there are infinitely many different distribution with the same maximizing entropy.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen How did you arrive at this conclusion? I don't follow.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Ah, maybe you treat two normal distributions with different mean as different distributions... this is correct, but I have the impression that the whole MaxEnt framework is about finding the distribution _family_.

Comment: Well, say that you want maxent distribution on $(-\infty, \infty)$ with variance one and some unknown mean. Using your result, then for example $\text{N}(-13,1)$ or $\text{N}(107, 1)$ or ... all have the same maximizing entropy. Otherwise I misunderstood your claim?

Comment: Why is it about finding the distribution family? Jaynes used maxent to choose a prior distribution fulfilling some restraints. If the restraints do not give me a unique distribution I dont understand how that may be useful to me?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen No, you're correct, they both are MaxEnt distributions compared to any other distribution outside the normal family. As for your second comment, you can always fix the mean if you like, and declare that the normal is the MaxEnt for given common variance and mean. It is just the case it is also MaxEnt for just the variance as common, irrespective of whether this is useful or not.